# BigQuery with dbt - Find frequency distribution of STRING Columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbt

I am using [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/) to find the frequency distribution of STRING datatype columns for all the tables, given a schema. This is the macro I have come up with following the [blog](https://rittmananalytics.com/blog/tag/dbt).

```
{%- macro col_freq(table_schema) -%}

{{ config(schema='profiles') }}

{% set tables = dbt_utils.get_relations_by_prefix(table_schema, '') %}

SELECT * FROM (
{% for table in tables %}
  SELECT *
  FROM
(
  WITH
    `table` AS (SELECT * FROM {{ table }} ),
    table_as_json AS (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'^{|}$', '') AS ROW FROM `table` AS t ),
    pairs AS (SELECT REPLACE(column_name, '"', '') AS column_name, IF (SAFE_CAST(column_value AS STRING)='null',NULL, column_value) AS column_value
              FROM table_as_json,UNNEST(SPLIT(ROW, ',"')) AS z,UNNEST([SPLIT(z, ':')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)]]) AS column_name,UNNEST([SPLIT(z, ':')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]]) AS column_value ),
    str_cols AS (
      SELECT
      split(replace('{{ table }}','`',''),'.' )[safe_offset(0)] as table_catalog,
      split(replace('{{ table }}','`',''),'.' )[safe_offset(1)] as table_schema,
      split(replace('{{ table }}','`',''),'.' )[safe_offset(2)] as table_name,
      column_name,
      column_value
      FROM pairs),
   matching_cols AS (
     SELECT str_cols.table_catalog, str_cols.table_schema, str_cols.table_name, str_cols.column_name, column_value FROM str_cols
      JOIN
      (
        SELECT
          table_catalog,
          table_schema,
          table_name,
          column_name
        FROM
          {{ table_schema }}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE data_type='STRING'
      ) sample
      ON str_cols.table_catalog = sample.table_catalog
      AND str_cols.table_schema = sample.table_schema
      AND str_cols.table_name = sample.table_name
      AND str_cols.column_name = sample.column_name
    ),
    profile AS (
      SELECT
            table_catalog,
            table_schema,
            table_name,
            column_name,
            column_value,
            COUNT(1) as frequency
      FROM matching_cols
      GROUP BY  table_catalog,
                table_schema,
                table_name,
                column_name, column_value
    )

    SELECT * FROM profile
)
{%- if not loop.last %}
    UNION ALL
{%- endif %}
{% endfor %}
)

{%- endmacro -%}
```

This works well except for columns that are unique like `email`. I want to avoid computing frequency distribution for columns with the percentage of unique values = 1.0. I am able to calculate the unique percent, but I am not able to use it to filter which is where I am stuck. Any ideas on how to do it?

`safe_divide(COUNT(DISTINCT column_value),COUNT(*)) AS pct_unique`